# Blender Game Engine - Shadeless Textures?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, game-engine, light, texture-baking

Blender has an option to make a material shadeless. If you make a game and want a lightmap from Cycles, you can remove all the lights. But, if you want a normal map or more in your game, it is impossible...The normal map can be lightened by fake lamps and spots which are at the same place as the lights in cycles are. So, if I have 2 textures on my material, one is the pre-baked texture with all the lights and is set to shadeless. The other texture on this material is a normal map, the normal map isn't set to shadeless.

The end result is:
You have an object that is shadeless, but with the normal map you have an object that looks like a render from Cylces, BUT it is in realtime!

Is there anyway to make textures shadeless?

Answer (score 3):

Is this what you're looking for?

Just check the small box that says *shadeless* in the materials tab.

[image: Shadeless]

Answer (score 0):

Instead create two separate materials one shadless and one not shadless.  Then you mix them in node editor and create a black and white map to plug into the mix factor telling it which areas get which material. Also plug in a color ramp between this map and the mix factor input to help you fine tune the areas.